# How to have this format "2020-08-08T03:20:14.362+00:00"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

I have tried using

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```

this gives output like **2020-08-08T03:20:14.362Z**

how to get **2020-08-08T03:20:14.362+00:00** as output

Comment: why do we need +00:00? Isn't .362Z the timezone offset?

Comment: This is my requirement.

Comment: @jmp—just the "Z", which indicates UTC so no offset.

Comment: `console.log(new Date().toISOString().replace('Z', '+00:00'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function format(date) {
  return date.split('Z')[0]+'+00:00';
}

console.log(format(new Date().toISOString()));
```

Comment: `replace('Z','+00:00')` would be more efficient.

Comment: I'd also personally just have to `.toISOString()` as part of the format function itself just so it doesn't have to be a string that is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/), `format()` method

```js
const res = dateFns.format(new Date())

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```